# What Ubuntu / Linux podcasts are most helpful?

Tags: community

Which podcasts in either the Ubuntu or general Linux categories are the most helpful or most enjoyable.

One podcast per answer which could be voted independently would be useful and possibly mentioning if it is highly technical, generally informative, or just fun.

Answer (score 15):

I also want to add a plug for the [Ubuntu UK podcast](http://podcast.ubuntu-uk.org/). Produced by the UK loco team, more family friendly, but less controversial.

Answer (score 14):

Not exclusively Ubuntu but Dan and Fab at [Linux Outlaws](http://linuxoutlaws.com/podcast) have a great podcast. Recorded live usually on a Monday evening (UK time)

Comment: A great podcast, but a caveat: it's not a podcast where the hosts watch their language. :)

Comment: +1 Fan and Dan do wander off topic at times but the informal style and the personalities of the presenters make this a great listen.

Answer (score 6):

[Full Circle Podcast](http://fullcirclemagazine.org/category/podcast/) by the Full Circle Magazine.

Answer (score 6):

I like [FLOSS Weekly](http://twit.tv/FLOSS) which is about Free Libre Open Source Software. This is hosted by [Leo Laporte](http://leoville.com/) and [Randal Schwartz](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/) along with a guest host (sometimes). It is not exclusively on Linux, but they are a great introduction to a lot of the Open Source software thats available out there.

Comment: Leo Laport has not been on FOSS Weekly for several months now, Randal has a series of co-hosts

Comment: Yeah, but I believe the show is still produced and distributed by Leo

Answer (score 4):

The [Tuxradar Podcast](http://tuxradar.com/podcast) by some editors of Linux Format Magzine is a show recorded every two weeks which includes some news about the Linux and Free Software world, a lot of commenting and discussing and a lot of fun (jokes, challenges) too. The guys don't take themselves too seriously and you shouldn't do either.

Answer (score 1):

[The Linux Action Show](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/?cat=4) is a lot of fun.

Answer (score 0):

While no longer in production, the [Linux Reality](http://www.linuxreality.com/) podcast is an excellent way to improve your understanding of Linux and the concepts surrounding it. The full show is 100 episodes long, and each covers a different part of Linux.